# How do I format JSON data to send message in a table format to Microsoft Teams using POSTMAN or PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-teams

I have a webhook for a specific channel of MS Teams. I have to send a message to that channel in the table format. The table will have a header and body. I am able to send a simple text message to MS Teams channel using POSTMAN and PHP cURL.

JSON format should be valid here: https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Are you trying to make table made out of textual data? If so, check out: https://github.com/sorensen/ascii-table

Comment: I just want an example json format which is valid here: https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [column set](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ColumnSet.html) in adaptive card to render a table like card

Example: Card Json -

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "TItle1",
                            "separator": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body4"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "style": "accent"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "title2"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body2"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "style": "good"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "title3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator": true,
                            "text": "body6"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "style": "warning"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the card rendered as below:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the border to make each cell separated from others, then it will be more readable?
BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: Currently you cannot add border to the columns but you can add style to the column to differentiate between columns. Updated card Json with style.

Comment: Problem: While I am trying to post message through POSTMAN it says "Summary or Text is required." Status: 400, Bad Request

Comment: Could you please check the text fields in the card you are sending?

Comment: While I am adding text the body(table) is not being posted!

Comment: The only text is being posted!

Comment: Are you able send card as table? still you are facing any issues?

Comment: I am not able to send a card as a table? Same issue!

Comment: Does webhook support AdaptiveCard ??

Comment: Incoming webhook support the adaptivecard

Comment: But when I send a post request it says "Summary or Text is required." Status: 400, Bad Request. And if I add text only text is posted not the table!

Comment: Are to trying for incoming webhook? could you please try the same card which i have shared?

Comment: I am trying the same card you provided. POSTMAN shows "Summary or Text is required." Status: 400, Bad Request

Comment: Could you please share request body?